# C++ Can't mix up a word

Tags: c++

Im my source code, I just can't get mixed up my word, it's getting me anything I don't want.

I have no errors, no warning but for an example if I put: papa, it's giving me ' p a ', why ?
Thank's for your help !

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

string melangeLettre(string mot);
int main()
{
    cout << "Saisissez un mot mystere: \n> ";
    string motMystere{};
    cin >> motMystere;

    cout << "Quel est ce mot ? \n";
    string const newMot = melangeLettre(motMystere);
    cout << newMot << endl;

    return {0};
}

string melangeLettre(string mot)
{
    size_t random = chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    mt19937 gen{random};
    string newMot{};

    for (unsigned int i{}; i < mot.size(); ++i)
    {
        uniform_int_distribution<> getNbr(0, mot.size());
        newMot.push_back(mot[getNbr(gen)]);
        mot.erase(i, 1);
    }

    return newMot;
}
```

Comment: Prefer to pass strings by `const std::string` so compiler doesn't need to make copies.

Comment: If your goal is to just shuffle the string, what's wrong with just using `std::shuffle`?

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems in your code. Your choosen distribution:

```
uniform_int_distribution<> getNbr(0, mot.size());
```

can result in numbers *including* `mot.size()` which is past the end of the string. The last character in a non-empty string will have an index of `mot.size()-1`.

In this code:

```
newMot.push_back(mot[getNbr(gen)]);
mot.erase(i, 1);
```

you copy a character to the new word and then delete a different character from the original word (it could be the same character but only by chance). You probably want to delete the same character you add to the new word like:

```
auto j = getNbr(gen);
newMot.push_back(mot[j]);
mot.erase(j, 1);
```

Your loop iterates too few times because you are deleting characters from the word in each loop. Because of this you really just need to iterate until your original word is empty.

These three things change the loop in your function to:

```
while (mot.size() > 0)
{
    uniform_int_distribution<> getNbr(0, mot.size()-1);
    auto j = getNbr(gen);
    newMot.push_back(mot[j]);
    mot.erase(j, 1);
}
```